# My c# form change when i excute in another laptop

Tags: c#

After weeks of do it my c# project I get problem in the end   that when I execute my application form in another laptop the form change, some laptop get bigger form and some laptop my form get small and i cant see some button and picture

[image]

as u can see form this picture that i can see my Shutdown button , i tried to give every button a location in the load but this don't give any result

thank you for your help

Comment: Is it related to DPI?

Comment: Without source code or even the slightest hint of what UI Framework is being used, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: The resolution is different on the other device from the device on which the application was built.

Comment: You've only mentioned "C#" and "form", so at best any answer would be a guess. But it sounds to me like you need to use component achoring

Comment: probably related to screen resolution. It perhaps could have occurred to you _before_ writing the code that some people use different screen sizes and resolutions? And then you could have researched techniques that people commonly use to deal with that.

Comment: I didnt know that before that i need technique for diferrent screen solution but is good experience now that i will learn from

Comment: Probably DPI related. Some people prefer a higher DPI which messes up some applications.

Comment: c# Winforms application

Answer (score 1):

To be able to see all controls in all window sizes you need to:

- enable scroll by setting AutoScroll of the form to true (according to your description this is what you probably should do)
- you may also want to set Anchor to some controls so that they change their position when you change window size.
- if you need some real custom things you can use the Resize event of the form